# Mood median test

Tags: rstudio

I have two vectors, and I would like to use a statistic test to know if their median are equal, but I don't know how to do that with RStudio.
Is there someone who could help me ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You should use boxplot.

Read the description of it.  You can make notches=T, to include more stats on the graph.

Also, be sure to assign boxplot to a name to gather the stats from it

```
info<-boxplot(your.vectors)
```